# Problem with htaccess GET form variables in a rewritten url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

Essentially my problem is thus; I have a MVC system that redirects all requests to index.php on my site. I have a rewrite rule in my htaccess file to handle those requests like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zAZ\_\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z\_\-]+)\/([^\/?]*) /?module=$1&class=$2&event=$3
```

Which translates urls into these type of urls

```
http://example.com/users/login/
http://example.com/users/info/me
```

My problem is that I also want GET variables to be applied and used in the URL like so

```
http://example.com/users/login/?var1=val1&var2=val2
http://example.com/users/info/me?var1=val2...
```

I've written two different regexes that work perfectly well in a my workbench (expresso) and I've tested them out in PHP however they refuse to work in htaccess. They're not particular complex, I have tried:

```
^([a-zAZ_\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z_\-]+)\/([^\/\?]*)[\?]*(.*) /?module=$1&class=$2&event=$3&$4
and
^([a-zAZ_\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z_\-]+)\/([^\/\?]*)(?(?=\?)\?(.+)) /?module=$1&class=$2&event=$3&$4
```

Neither of these work and I'm racking my brains as to why. Essentially it just doesn't recognise the fourth group and returns nothing I thought it might have been due to it being next to an ampersand but I did &var=$4 as a test and it still fell over.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me insane.

Thanks in advance,
Rupert S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all, this is what you need:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)/([a-z_-]+)/([^/?]*) /?module=$1&class=$2&event=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

`[QSA]` will append the additional GET parameters to the rewritten query string.

`[NC]` since it is case insensitive, no need for A-Z matches

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but the problem is still there, the extra GET variable don't show up in the scope. I missed out the [DC] bit. It's an internal redirect that I'm doing, I've got one set up that works but doesn't allow you to add 'extra' get variables to it. 
RewriteRule ^([a-zAZ_\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z_\-]+)\/([^\/]*) /?module=$1&class=$2&event=$3 [NC] was the original. I want to be able to add 'on the fly' vars to that particular call i.e. example.com/forum/thread/?showPostNumber=1&threadId=123
Where forum is the module and thread is the class but the added variables interact with that module

Comment: Why do you want the module, class, etc. get parameters to be visible? It is far more complicated this way. [QSA] flag allows you to append additional query string to the rewritten url, but what I wrote in my answer won't rewrite anything with get parameters.

Comment: I don't want the module class and event params to be visible, I want every other GET var to be visible, I want it like the example I gave i.e. in the url bar it would show as
/forum/thread/ and would be
/?module=forum&class=thread internally
and
/forum/thread/?threadId=123&showpostHeader=1 would be
/?module=forum&class=thread&threadId=123&showpostHeader=1 internally
I want variables specific to that module to be visible as regular GET vars

Comment: Ah fantastic, just used the QSA flag and it's doing what I want, thanks very much :)

Comment: I also changed my answer, now that I understand what you wanted ;)